# Javascript replace with 3 parameters

Tags: javascript

How does the following Javascript replace method work ?

```
records.replace(index, 1, this.get(`model.data.${index}`))
```

I have normally seen JS replace() with 2 parameters, but not sure how does 3 parameters work ?

records is an array of objects (for individual table row rendering)

Comment: What do you mean by three parameters, replace function signature is this `str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`

Comment: What is `records`?

Comment: records is an array of objects (for individual table row rendering)

Comment: As TKoL asked, what is `records`? String? Array? Something completely different? Give us come context, without more information this is difficult to answer.

Comment: That is very odd, arrays in JavaScript do not have a `replace` method by default. What libraries/frameworks are you using?

Comment: I am using EmberJS...sorry for not adding the details in the initial question

Comment: @testndtv Maybe you want this: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy/methods/replace?anchor=replace

Answer (score 1):

> I have normally seen JS replace() with 2 parameters

The `replace` method you've seen was probably the string's one.

My educated guess is that `records` is *not* a string, then.

So, you should check what's `records` actually is. The method is not part of JS language, so it's either `records` an Object defined by the dev, or is extending the prototype of some built-in type (brrr).

To me, it looks like this method shared similarity with [array's splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

If `records` is an array, on an array-like object, the developer could actually added `replace` as alias of `splice`, maybe because it seemed to him more clear about what it does (again, I'm just guessing, I don't have enough data).

If my guess is correct, this line would replace in the `records` array / array-like, `1` element, at the index pointed by `index`, with the value returned by `this.get(…)`.

Comment: `the replace method you've seen was probably the string's one.` even that accepts only two parameters mate not three, if you pass the third one with comma it doesn't have any impact

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, that's what I'm saying, probably I wasn't clear enough :) The OP said `I have normally seen JS replace() with 2 parameters`, so I replied `the replace method you've seen was probably the string's one.` (that, in fact,  takes 2 parameters)

Comment: @ZERO well yeah with the amount of data provided in question it's not clear, but to me that line doesn't make sense so i pointed out. P.s:- i didn't downvoted :)

Comment: @CodeManiac it might be my english but I don't understand what doesn't make sense on that sentence: the OP said that have seen only `replace` methods with two args till now, and I said that probably the `replace` method he seen was the String ones, since the string's replace takes two args. :) You said that "it doesn't make sense" since String's replace takes only two parameters, but that's exactly what I'm also saying, so I honestly don't understand. P.S. I don't care about the downvote anyway, np :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using Ember.js as stated in a comment, I would assume that you are referring to Ember.js' replace method. It takes three parameters: index to start replacing at, number of elements that should be removed from the array, and finally an array of elements to add to your array.

For more information, check [this](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy/methods/replace?anchor=replace) out.